# Reducing database load from consecutive queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application which calls the database multiple times to achieve one simple goal.

A little information about this application; In short, the application scrapes data from a webpage & stores specific information from this page into a database. The important information in this query is: Player name, Position. There can be multiple sitting at one specific position, kill points & Class

- Player name has every potential to change or remain the same every day
- Regarding the Position, there can be multiple sitting in one position
- Kill points has the potential to increase or remain the same every day
- Class, there is only 2 possibilities that a name can be, Ex: A can change to B or remain A (same in reverse), but cannot be C,D,E,F

The player name can change at any particular day, Position can also change dependent on the kill point increase from the last update which spins back around to the goal. This is to search the database day by day, from the current date to as far back as 2021-02-22 starting at the most recent entry for a player name and back track to the previous day to check if that player name is still the same or has changed.

What is being used as a main reference to the change is the kill points. As the days go on, this number will either be the exact same or increase, it can never decrease.

So now onto the implementation of this application.

The first query which runs finds the most recent entry for the player name

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [changes] WHERE [CharacterName]=@charname AND [Territory]=@territory AND [Archived]=0  ORDER BY [Recorded] DESC
```

Then continue to check the previous days entries with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [changes] WHERE [Territory]=@territory AND [CharacterName]=@charname AND [Recorded]=@searchdate AND ([Class] LIKE '%{Class}%' OR [Class] LIKE '%{GetOpposite(Class)}%' AND [Archived]=0 )
```

If no results are found, will then proceed to find an alternative name with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM [changes] WHERE [Kills] <= @kills AND [Recorded]='{Data.Recorded.AddDays(-1):yyyy-MM-dd}' AND [Territory]=@territory AND [Mode]=@mode AND ([Class] LIKE @original OR [Class] LIKE @opposite) AND [Archived]=0  ORDER BY [Kills] DESC
```

The aim of the query above is to get the top 5 entries that are the closest possible matches & Then cross references with the day ahead

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [changes] WHERE [CharacterName]=@CharacterName AND [Territory]=@Territory AND [Recorded]=@SearchedDate AND [Archived]=0
```

So with checking the day ahead, if the character name is not found in the day ahead, then this is considered to be the old player name for this specific character, else after searching all 5 of the results and they are all found to be present in the day aheads searches, then this name is considered to be new to the table.

Now with the date this application started to run up to today's date which is over 400 individual queries on the database to achieve one goal.

It is also worth a noting that this table grows by 14,400 - 14,500 Rows each and every day.

The overall question to this specific? Is it possible to bring all these queries into less calls onto the database, reduce queries & improve performance?

Comment: CharacterName is know, so you should also be able to find 1 Class. This could lead to the change of     `[CharacterName]=@charname AND [Recorded]=@searchdate AND ([Class] LIKE '%{Class}%'....`  to: ``[CharacterName]=@charname AND [Recorded]=@searchdate AND ([Class]=@Class}....``, which is easier to find (Because it can use an index)

Comment: Can you please provide your table definitions involved here? Also you should probably stop using `*` in your `SELECT` list, which in itself may be a performance improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do to improve performance will be based on what parts of the application stack you can manipulate. Things to try:

**Store Less Data** - Database content retrieval speed is largely based on how well the database is ordered/normalized and just how much data needs to be searched for each query. Managing a cache of prior scraped pages and only storing data when there's been a change between the current scrape and the last one would guarantee less redundant requests to the db.

**Separate specific classes of data** - Separating data into dedicated tables would allow you to query a specific table for a specific character, etc... effectively removing one where clause.

**Reduce time between queries** - Less incoming concurrent requests means less resource contention and faster response times to prior requests.

**Use another data structure** - The only reason you're using top() is because you need data ordered in some specific way (most-recent, etc...). If you just used a code data structure that keeps the data ordered and still easily-query-able you could then perhaps offload some sql requests to this structure instead of the db.

The suggestions above are not exhaustive, but what you do to improve performance is largely a function of what in the application stack you have the ability to modify.